# Why ng-bind does not work with array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am wanting to create a bind to an element with an array, for when the array is changed, the HTML to be updated. But, it's not work.

*HTML*

```
<body ng-controller="Game as game">

<div>
    <span ng-bind="game.testString"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <span ng-bind="game.testArray"></span>
</div>

<input type="button" ng-click="game.btnAddLetter()" value="Change">
</body>
```

*JS*

```
angular.module('notesApp', [])
    .controller('Game', [function() {
        var self = this;
        self.testString = 'a';
        self.testArray = ['a'];

        self.btnAddLetter = function() {
            self.testString = 'X';
            self.testArray.push('X');
        }
    }]);
```

I expected the two span would be updated, however, only the `testString` has been updated. For what reason did this happen? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the [**`JSON`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json) filter:

```
<span ng-bind="game.testArray | json"></span>
```

Comment: Why if I not use this filter, the element is not updated?

Comment: Because `ngBind` expects an expression, as documented: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind. You also can use `{{ game.testArray }}` if you are working with primitive types...